# Find all students not enrolled in a class (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Been trying to figure this one out for a while and I'm really stumped.

So I have a danceclass model

```
class Danceclass < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :danceclass_students
has_many :students, through: :danceclass_students
```

I Have a student model:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :danceclass_students
has_many :danceclasses, through: :danceclass_students
```

I have my join model:

```
class DanceclassStudent < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :student
belongs_to :danceclass
```

I use `@danceclass.students` to get a list of all students enrolled in a `danceclass`. How do I get the opposite of that? IE. All students not enrolled in this `danceclass`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with all students then apply a negative where clause to remove the ones you do not want.

```
Student.joins(:danceclass_students).where.not(danceclass_students: {danceclass_id: @danceclass.id })
```

The `joins` is needed since the `where` statement are trying to reduce based on the ID on the bridge table

---

This will return all students not enrolled in the specific @danceclass if it is related to a single danceclass.  Not for your question, but leaving incase anyone else has this problem

```
Student.where.not(danceclass: @danceclass)
```

Comment: Is my association wrong? With that it tries to look at the students table: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'students.danceclass_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `students`.* FROM `students` WHERE (`students`.`danceclass_id` != 1)

Comment: Oh whoops, mine will work for a has_one relationship.  I'll update it for the has_many through relationship.

Comment: Thank you so much! So that would give me students not enrolled in the current class but what about students not enrolled in any classes as well? I have a new student that has not enrolled in any class yet so he has no records on the join table. I need him to be able show up in this list of available students to enroll in a class.

Comment: You would need to do an `left_outer_joins` instead of `joins` and check for not that ID.  This will bring in records with `nil` in that table as is your case

Comment: I'm guessing I can only use left_out_joins in Rails 5 and not 4.2?

Comment: Well I upgraded to rails 5 and got left_out_joins to work however, still not seeing that student with no classes.