# Find all students not enrolled in specific course

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am trying to solve this one but no success till now.

I have 3 models.

Course Model:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :student_courses
    has_many :students, :through => :student_courses
end
```

Student Model:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :student_courses
    has_many :courses, :through => :student_courses
end
```

Joining Model:

```
class StudentCourse < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :student
    belongs_to :course
end
```

I am trying to send to the view only the students that aren't enrolled in the currently selected course so the opposite of @course.students

I have found this [Find all students not enrolled in a class (rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40854192/find-all-students-not-enrolled-in-a-class-rails)
Which looks very promising except that it doesn't include new students that aren't enrolled in any course, in that question using left_outer_joins is a proposition which doesn't appear to work for them but doesn't help me as I can't update rails over 4.2.5 and it requires rails 5.

Anyone can think of an other solution?

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: also is this an accurate rephrase (psudo-sql) of you query "return all `students` whose `count` of (`student_courses` where `course_id = ?`) is `0`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Student.where.not(id: @course.students).all
```

Answer (score 0):

in your Course model you can do something like this

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :student_courses
    has_many :students, :through => :student_courses
    ...
    def not_enrolled_students
      Student.where.not(id: self.students)
    end
end
```

now anywhere in your app you can call `Course.first.not_enrolled_students`

Answer (score 0):

For those who are like me and trying to find the similar **"All courses the current user is not enrolled in"**:

```
Course.where.not(id: current_user.courses)
```